# Angular2 RC5: where to include HttpModule and FormsModule?

Tags: angular

I have a root module, shared module and some other feature modules.

HttpModule and FormsModule are needed in feature modules, should I import them in root module or shared module? Also, where should I import third party libraries such as "ng2-bootstrap".

Comment: Have you end up with something? Also wondering if it's a good choice to re-export often used modules from shared module and then only import shared module in other feature modules.

Answer (score 0):

A module should declare all dependencies. Add modules and libraries to the modules that depend on them.
So that for users of your modules, adding your module automatically adds everything it depends on.

Comment: But it still works if I export the angular2 build-in modules like HttpModule, commonModule and FormsModule in a shared module. Then import shared module in every feature module, so that I don't import those modules repeatedly in every feature module. This way makes my code more clean.
It seems angular2 official docs doesn't explain which way is better, which make me confused.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in **SharedModule**.

HttpModule should be a LazyLoadModule, means, it should be called onle when you need it.

In **CoreModule** instead, you would have your EagerLoadModules, things that are static and won't change during the application life time. Means, things like: Menu, Breadcrumb or other components / services, which are visible or static in every single page of your application.

You might not want a http request in every component / page, so it also depends on your requirement.